# How to show that $n^{-1}S_n \rightarrow 0$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X_1, X_2,....X_n $ be a sequence of $m-dependent$ random variables and these are uniformly bounded and $E[X_n]=0$. Show that $n^{-1}S_n \rightarrow 0$ a.s .

I proved the similar problems, by using first Borel Cantelli lemma and Chebyshev's inequality. In that case, $X_1, X_2,....X_n $ was independent.

Can anyone suggest how to use $m-dependent$ condition here?

Comment: This convergence is a.s .

Comment: Does m-dependent mean that $X_i$ and $X_{i+j}$ are independent for $j > m$?

Comment: Split $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ into blocks of some size depending on $n$ with gaps of size $m$ between them.

Answer (score 3):

Not the most elegant, but I think this works:

Define $Y^j_n = X_{j + (n-1)m}$ for $j = 1, \cdots, m$.
Then each $\{Y^j_n\}$ is a sequence of independent, uniformly bounded, mean zero random variables, so
$$
n^{-1} S^j_n = n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^n Y^j_n \to 0 \quad a.s.
$$
by your earlier result.
But
$$
S_N = \sum_{j=1}^{m} S^j_{\lceil N / m \rceil} - o(N)
$$
which implies
$$
N^{-1}S_N = \frac{\lceil N / m \rceil}{N}\sum_{j=1}^m \frac{1}{\lceil N / m \rceil} S^j_{\lceil N / m \rceil} - o(1) \to 0\quad a.s.
$$